# if x>d and x<w en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un pequeño problema con `if x>d and x<w` , me sale un error de que no está bien la sintaxis, pero no entiendo que parte está mal. Espero que podaís ayudarme.

```
try:
    octects = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print('Vuelve a introducir el tamaño del bloque.')
    octects = int(input())
**if (octects => 8) and (octects <= 65464):**
```

Sería porque no está dentro del try ¿? Gracias.

Comment: En lugar de `=>` debe ser `>=`. Y por cierto que Python también admite esta otra sintaxis, más compacta y legible:  `if 8 <= octets <= 65464:`  (y los paréntesis no son necesarios)

Comment: @abulafia acabo de ponerlo asi: if (octects >= 8) and (octects =< 65464): pero me sigue dando error. ¿Me he confundido?

Comment: saludos te sugiero revisar los operadores lógicos: https://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/cursos/fpr/wiki/index.php/Operadores_en_Python

Comment: Mayor o igual que ">= "....menor o igual que "<= ".....

Comment: si, es sintaxis, menor o igual a <=, mayor o igual >=. siempre piensalo de esta forma cuando estés comparando datos, no se pregunta, por decirlo de alguna forma, si x es igual o mayor (=>), se pregunta si es mayor o igual a. Saludos

Comment: Hola Anabel, bienvenida a [es.so] primero, aparte del typo ya comentado repasa la lógica, si no me equivoco y  estás intentando validar la entrada del usuario, nada te asegura que en el input del except no se ingrese un valor que no se pueda convertir a entero, y en este caso no estás resguardada bajo el try  por lo que tendrás una excepción y el programa terminará y no se si es esto lo que quieres...

Comment: @Anabel Sí, te has confundido al cambiarlo a `if (octects >= 8) and (octects =< 65464)`, pues has cambiado también el segundo. No existe un operador `=<` como no existe tampoco `=>`. Aparte de eso, como te dice FJSevilla, la lógica no es correcta. Piensa qué pasa si el usuario introduce por segunda vez un dato malo (por ejemplo escribe "hola" las dos veces que le pregunta)

Answer (score 2):

El error está en la primera condición del `if`. Escribiste `=>` lo cual no coincide con ningun operador de python, el operador mayor igual es `>=`. El `if` corregido queda asi:

```
if (octects >= 8) and (octects <= 65464):
```

Adicional, puedes reescribirlo como:

```
if 8 <= octects <= 65464:
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría algo como:

```
while True:
    try:
        octects = int(input("Ingresar un dato: "))
        assert(octects in range(8, 65465))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Favor de introducir un número")
    except AssertionError:
        print("Número ingresado está fuera del rango")
```